# wrong level of factor after using reshape command

Tags: r, reshape

I have the following data,

```
   Sample_ID   SNP_Name Genotype Phenotype CV.Group
1     AUS002  rs1028005       AA         1        4
2     AUS002  rs4788050       TC         1        4
3     AUS002 rs17143930       CC         1        4
4     AUS002  rs3920214       AA         1        4
5     AUS002  rs1862520       GG         1        4
6     AUS002  rs1461224       AC         1        4
```

which I did reshape it with the command below :

```
reshaped.data <- reshape(merged.data, timevar = "SNP_Name", idvar = c("Sample_ID","Phenotype","CV.Group"), direction = "wide")
```

It works fine by giving me what I want which to group it according to `Sample_ID` and each of the variable will give three categories only (genotype data).

```
      Sample_ID Phenotype CV.Group Genotype.rs1028005 Genotype.rs4788050
1        AUS002         1        4                 AA                 TC
4039     AUS003         1        3                 GG               <NA>
7927     AUS004         1        4                 AA                 TC
11965    AUS005         0        2                 AG                 TT
16003    AUS007         0        2                 AA                 TC
```

However, when I try to tabulate one of the variable it shows other level as well when it supposed to be only three (for example AA,AG and GG). Where it goes wrong?

```
table(reshaped.data$Phenotype,reshaped.data$Genotype.rs1028005)

  -- AA AC AG AT CC CG GC GG TA TC TG TT
0  0 45  0 35  0  0  0  0  4  0  0  0  0
1  0 16  0 12  0  0  0  0  3  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: You can use `droplevels` to remove the unused levels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume this as a case of unused levels after reshaping the dataset.  To remove those `levels` in the 'factor' variable, we can call either `factor` once more or use the function `droplevels` to drop those unused levels.

```
table(droplevels(reshaped.data$Phenotype),
                 droplevels(reshaped.data$Genotype.rs1028005))
```

Or just

```
 reshaped.data <- droplevels(reshaped.data)
 table(reshaped.data[,c('Phenotype', 'Genotype.rs1028005')])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works fine with your suggestion. The second command helps me to do it for the entire 4000 SNPs.